# Where is Quick Print for QGIS 1.8?

Tags: qgis, printing, extensions

Just installing Qgis 1.8 Lisboa, but I can't find "Quick Print" Extension.
Any idea where to catch it again?

Answer (score 2):

Quick print plugin has been replaced by Easy print plugin. You find that in the CatAIS Repository